# How to replace all instances of a value in one DataFrame column with a value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where some values in column A are zero, and I want to replace those based on the value in column C for that row. In my real usage there are more columns (and I don't necessarily know what order they will come back in), hence the lookup of the column index.

Here's what I have, but I suspect there is a much neater and pythonic way to achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[0,5,6],[7,8,9],[0,11,12]],columns=['A','B','C'])  
    print('Input:\n',df)

    x = df.columns.get_loc('A')
    y = df.columns.get_loc('C')

    for r in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.iloc[r,x] == 0:
            df.iloc[r,x] = df.iloc[r,y]-2

    print('\nOutput:\n',df)

main()
```

And this is the required result:

```
Input:
    A   B   C
0  1   2   3
1  0   5   6
2  7   8   9
3  0  11  12

Output:
     A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

[EDIT] Thanks for the answers: they worked on the example I gave initially. I realized that the types in my real-world data are different: they come from a database call, and the DataFrame can have None when non-number values are missing.

This is a better example (using strings), and unfortunately the answers don't so far work for this, as the None is not being detected.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame([['Fred',2,'John'],[None,5,'Paul'],['Ginger',8,'George'],[None,11,'Ringo']],columns=['A','B','C'])  
    print('Input:\n',df)

    x = df.columns.get_loc('A')
    y = df.columns.get_loc('C')

    for r in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.iloc[r,x] is None:
            df.iloc[r,x] = df.iloc[r,y]

    print('\nOutput:\n',df)

main()


Input:
         A   B       C
0    Fred   2    John
1    None   5    Paul
2  Ginger   8  George
3    None  11   Ringo

Output:
         A   B       C
0    Fred   2    John
1    Paul   5    Paul
2  Ginger   8  George
3   Ringo  11   Ringo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.loc[df['A']==0, 'A'] = df['C'] - 2
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for my initial question. But I have run into an issue when my DataFrame has things other than numbers. Have edited question.

Comment: `None` in Python is special. Replace the condition `df['A']==0` with `df['A'].isnull()`. You can also use `df['A'].fillna(df['C'])`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `np.where()`:

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['A'] == 0,df['C']-2,df['A'])
```

Comment: I guess it should be df['A'] at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Via `np.where`:

```
df.A = np.where(df.A.eq(0), df.C.sub(2) , df.A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.A = np.where(df.A == 0, (df.C -2) ,df.A)
```